# Error while resolving conflicts after latest pull from master branch

Tags: git, git-pull, git-merge-conflict

I pulled latest remote master branch into my private branch but the automatic merge failed and there were conflicts I tried resolving them by accepting the changes from master branch with the command `git checkout --theirs <filename>` but it is throwing an error : pathspec 'filename' did not match any file(s) known to git. How do I resolve this?

Comment: What happens if you type `git fetch` and try again?

Comment: @HuyPhạm i won't be able to merge it into my private branch since there are conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should issue the command `git status` to know the right **relative path** of each file to pass to the `git checkout --theirs -- <FILE_NAMES_LIST>`.

Comment: Thanks @Antonio your suggestion worked there were discrepancies in file path.